Should profile picture URLs in ID tokens be publicly accessible or require authentication?
I’m building an OIDC provider and want to include the picture claim in the ID token to allow clients to fetch the user’s profile picture.
However, I’m unsure how to handle the security of the profile picture URL.
Should the URL be publicly accessible, allowing anyone with the link to view the image, or should the URL be protected, requiring the access token to authenticate requests?
